# Swipe in ionic 3 testing on Android device

Tags: android, ionic3, chart.js, swipe

I have a page that displays a line graph. I would like to detect gestures to update this chart with previous days' or next day's data. I am using swipe to detect gestures left and right by checking event.direction property.

The problem is after a few swipes either to the left or right, event.direction returns 1 for the same gestures instead of expected 2 or 4. When I just have a console.log('Printing swipe direction ' + event.direction); in my swipe(event) function without the rest of the chart rendering code this does not happen, I see the expected 2 or 4 values. The event.direction value is 1 for left and right swipes event when I pause long enough for the chart to be rendered before I perform a swipe again.
Has anyone encountered this? What can I do to make swipe handling reliable?

the html -

```
<ion-content>
 <div(swipe)="swipe($event)">
   <ion-card>       
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="chartDateString" (ionChange)="getNewData(0)">
    </ion-datetime>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-card-content>
    <canvas #lineCanvas></canvas>
   </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

the .ts

```
swipe(event) {
  console.log('Printing swipe direction ' + event.direction);
  let number = event.direction;

  //swipe left decrease date by one day
  if(number == 4){
    this.chartDate.setDate(this.chartDate.getDate() - 1);
  }
  //swipe right increase date by one day
  if(number == 2){
   this.chartDate.setDate(this.chartDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  this.chartDateString = this.chartDate.toISOString();
  //check if date is later than today's date.
  let today = new Date();
  if(this.chartDate > today){
    alert('No more data to display');
  }
  else{
    this.getNewData(number); //gets data from local storage and draws new chart 
  }
}
```

Here is my work environment-

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-sim : 6.1.2 
Node    : v9.5.0
npm     : 5.6.0 
OS      : macOS High Sierra
Xcode   : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Try to use (pan) instead (swipe), sometime it helps.

Comment: Thank you. (pan) seems to work - but its too sensitive for my purposes. A single gesture triggers multiple calls and its a struggle to view the charts serially. The slightest gesture triggers about 4 calls to refresh the chart :) But thats another problem altogether. I am going to leave this open a bit longer in case any one has other suggestions and then close it. Thank you again!

Comment: You can manualy detect speed and angle of pan =)

Comment: I see. I used a timer inside my function to limit the sensitivity for now. Its not great but will do for now. Thanks for your input.